# Extracting only one file type with Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to extract a number of pictures from a webpage.

The conventional method using:

Elements media = doc.select("[src]");

is of no use as there are 87 src tags on this page and i only require the 14 of type .jpg.

Is there a way to select only a particular file type for extraction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the attribute-ends-with selector `[name$=value]`.

```
Elements pngs = document.select("img[src$=.png]");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Jsoup selector cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `selector` API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)